# fusionChart is not loading with dynamic data using Json and C#

Tags: c#, jquery, json, charts, fusioncharts

I have the below code in code behind.

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
       {    
         hdndata.Value = ShowFusionChart();    
       }  

      public string ShowFusionChart()  
       { 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();     
        dt = LoadGrid();  
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();   
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>(); Dictionary<string, object> row;    

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)        
         { 
         row = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
         foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) 
           {  
         if (col.ColumnName.ToLower() == "linkname")  
             row.Add("label", dr[col]);  
         if (col.ColumnName.ToLower() == "countno") 
             row.Add("value", dr[col]); 
        } 
        rows.Add(row);  
      }   
       return serializer.Serialize(rows); 
    }  

    Public DataTable LoadGrid()  
     {  
     // This code block is generating a DataTable from database 
     }
```

I am having the below sample data into my hiddenfield  'hdndata' as

```
[{"label":"Products","value":88},{"label":"Documents","value":77},{"label":"Videos","value":58}]
```

At the Design Page ......

```
 <div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>   
 <div id="chartContainer2"></div>   


<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.zune.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">  

   $(function () {    
 `enter code here`  
    alert($('#hdndata').val());// getting alert with Json Data.  
    FusionCharts.ready(function () {       

    var jdata ;  
    jdata = $('#hdndata').val();  
    //console.log(jdata);    

           var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({  
            type: "column2d",  
            renderAt: "chartContainer",  
            width: "500",  
            height: "300",  
            dataFormat: "json",  
            dataSource: {   
                "chart": {   
                    "caption": "Asset Tracking Report",   
                    "subCaption": "Microsite Report",   
                    "xAxisName": "Assets",   
                    "yAxisName": "Count",   
                    "theme": "zune"   
                },   
                "data": jdata   
            }   
        });    
        revenueChart.render("chartContainer");   

    });   
    });    


</script>
```

Still the Chart is not populated. No Error is showing. The message is 'No Data found to display'.

If I provide the static Json format data after  "data": then that works perfectly.

My Question is how to run the chart with dynamic data? Please help me to find my mistakes. Thank you All.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if your chart shows a "No data to display" message, it could be that your data doesn't contain any data that could be plotted by FusionCharts XT or incorrect data format.

The chart is rendered correctly by passing the data in the "jdata" variable appended to the JSON, as we had tested your code.

It seems the issue might be caused while fetching the data from the database and passing to the chart via "jdata" variable. Please recheck whether the "'$('#hdndata').val();" code is generating the correct data that needs to be passed to the chart.

Comment: Hi Sanjukta,
If I pass the Json data in the data part of chart, then chart is preparing perfectly. Also, I have checked that the hiddenfiled is geeting filled with the JSON data from database, I can see the value of hiddenfield from this line of code. alert($('#hdndata').val());

Comment: I have converted the data into JSON and then used the variable into chart.
jdata = JSON.parse($('#hdndata').val()); That works. Thank all.